# Trip to Germany (Frankfurt City - Frankfurt Hahn)

Tags: germany, airport-transfer, transportation, frankfurt, hhn

I would like to ask if you can indicate me some information and tricks regarding the transport services for the route: Frankfurt Hahn (Airport) to Frankfurt City. Is there a website? Can I let my luggage in Frankfurt in the railway station for few hours?

Thanks!

Comment: Some of the questions tagged [tag:hhn] may contain the information you need. Basically, there's a bus service; it takes about two hours.

Answer (score 3):

1. Information about getting to Frankfurt from the aiport is given on its [official website](http://www.hahn-airport.de/default.aspx?menu=by_bus&cc=en#). If you want to use public transportation, there is also the possibility to use a regional bus to the next train station, and take the train from there. You can search for such connections on [bahn.de](https://www.bahn.com/en/view/index.shtml) - use "Hahn Flughafen Terminal 2" as starting point of your journey.
2. There are luggage lockers at the Frankfurt/Main main train station. They are coin-operated.